# Unresolved reference: arguments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't know for what reason, I am getting **Unresolved reference: arguments** when I build the project. Could not understand what is that I am doing wrong? Can someone point me to whats going wrong? I am using support fragment android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

```
public class Tab1() : Fragment() {
    val TAG = "Tab1";
    companion object {
        public fun create(uuid: String): Tab1 {
            val history:Tab1 = Tab1()
            history.arguments.putString("uuid",uuid)
            return history
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false)
        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I got this resolved with following implementation. Thanks.

```
companion object Factory {
        public fun newInstance(uuid: String): Tab1 {
            val history:Tab1 = Tab1()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString("uuid",uuid)
            history.setArguments(args)
            return history
        }
    }
```